# Square boxes appearing on websites in Google Chrome

Tags: html, wordpress, google-chrome

These square boxes have been appearing on the websites that I've worked before.
They show up in the middle of the text randomly.

All the sites are in Wordpress but have different themes and different hosts.
But it only shows in Google Chrome. My Chrome version is 56.0.2924.87.

[image]

Does someone know what is going on or how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Is there something that it isnt displaying that is being replaced by the square? In that case it could be that the particular font isnt able to display that character.

Comment: No, it just appears. It doesn't even replace the space, there wasn't even a  &nbsp; for example. =(
Maybe it's a problem with open sans...I don't know...